# Ubuntu loads desktop files slowly

Tags: login, unity-dash

After logging into Ubuntu (Unity), it takes about 30s before applications (`/usr/share/applications/*`) are shown in the dash. My personal files (images, music, ...) are listed immediately when entering a search term in the dash.
Why does it take so long to list these files?

Comment: go to system settings-privacy and off both "include online search results " and record activity. then observe the difference .

Comment: I keep these options disabled by default. However, *record activity* gets reenabled after every update. But it's working. Please repost this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to `system setting` then `privacy`  and off both -

`include online search results`

and

`record activity`

then observe the difference .

Answer (score 0):

go to system settings-privacy and off both "include online search results " and record activity. then observe the difference -Reposting [@Sushantip606](https://askubuntu.com/users/192102/sushantp606) Answer